# conditional variable assignment in JOLT modify-overwrite-beta

Tags: json, jolt

I need to assign a variable *unit* value depends on first letter of another variable *name*.
I.e. if *name* starts with 'S' unit shall be equal to 'n', otherwise it shall be the first letter of *name*.
I can't place substring function as a key and if I try to use another temp variable, I am getting duplicate key error.
I'd like to have it in the modify-overwrite-beta spec as I am doing some other transformation for the same block of JSON data.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hi Gary, can you please provide a minimal, reproducible example as input and desired output.

Comment: Hi Barbaros, You remember my previous question where you helped me with distance conversion. Product people added another condition: If businessType is sole proprietary, distance shall not be present in the request at all.